# How to allocate the 2d array of pointers using arguments of main function

Tags: c

Write a C program that take 2 integers as arguments. The program should allocate a 2D array of characters dynamically, read its data, print them, and finally free the array. The array dimensions of the array are taken from the main arguments.
my problem in this code run and input is correct but the output isn't correct 
run time error for output

```
    int main (int y,char *x[]){
    int i,j,v,b;
    v=atoi(x[1]);
    b=atoi(x[2]);
    char*m[v];

    for(i=0;i<v;i++)
        m[i]=(char*)malloc(b*sizeof(char));

    for(i=0;i<v;i++)
        for(j=0;j<b;j++)
            scanf("%s",&m[i][j]);

    for(i=0;i<v;i++){
        for(j=0;j<b;j++)
            printf("%s",m[i][j]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Your teacher gives good assignments, now you just have to explain what your problem is

Comment: yeah my problem I want to allocate 2d array of characters using the arguments of main function

Comment: Please edit your question and include any errors you are seeing and/or the expected-vs-actual output.

Comment: my answer helps you or what?

Comment: `scanf("%s",&m[i][j]);` fails. Do you want `scanf("%s",m[i]);` or `scanf("%c",&m[i][j]);`? Similarly the `printf` is hopeless.

Comment: scanf("%s",&m[i][j]); dosen't fail but the problem in the printf("%s",m[i][j]);

Comment: That asks for a string input to a character. Please take note of earlier comments, edit the question and not just repeat yourself.

Comment: yeah I want to write as example seven strings and the the output actual seven

Comment: In `printf("%s",m[i][j]);` the element `m[i][j]` is not a `char*` pointer as required by the `%s` format. It is just a `char`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int y,char *x[]){
    int i,j,v,b;
    v=atoi(x[1]);
    b=atoi(x[2]);
    char *m[v][b];//allocate the 2d array of pointers on stack

    for(i=0;i<v;i++){
        for(j=0;j<b;j++){
            char buff[128];
            scanf("%127s", buff);
            m[i][j] = malloc(strlen(buff)+1);
            strcpy(m[i][j], buff);
        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<v;i++){
        for(j=0;j<b;j++){
            printf("%s ", m[i][j]);
            free(m[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: but please explain to me      m[i][j] = malloc(strlen(buff)+1); what mean +1 ? because the '\0'
            strcpy(m[i][j], buff);

Comment: 1) count the length of the input string by `strlen`
2) it will be dynamically allocated  the area string of length +1 by `malloc`. `+1` for null-terminator(`'\0'`).
3) The string copy to ensure the area by `strcpy`.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to read a string in a character variable. That's obviously wrong!

Replace this -

```
for(i=0;i<v;i++)
    for(j=0;j<b;j++)
        scanf("%s",&m[i][j]);
```

With -

```
for(i=0;i<v;i++)
  scanf("%s",&m[i]);
```

Similarly it applies for printf also.

Please let me know if you are not clear on this.